# How do I stop user scroll on HTML

Tags: javascript, html

I am making a website which has different sections of text that I want the user to read in a specific order depending on their input. It is a pick-a-path gamebook type story. What I want to be able to do is to scroll to different divs depending on the id but also disable all user inputted scroll so they cannot move the webpage but I (by which I mean the computer) can.

Comment: there are ways to inhibit scrolling (see here for instance: http://output.jsbin.com/teqoqib/6/) but it will raise many problems. I think a better approach would be to hide all divs, and then only show the "current chapter" div, always one at a time

Comment: also check out this interesting project, maybe you can make use of it: https://github.com/Kartones/choose-your-adventure | demo: https://kartones.net/demos/021/?adventure-file=demo